# Is there a way to use EditText to underline errors in the text as the user enters it?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there a way to use EditText to underline errors in the text as the user enters it? Or an alternative control that allows that kind of formatting?

I'm trying to process text as a user is entering it. For example, if the user enters

> The current time is 80:30 at night.
> I'd like to underline *80:30* so that it's obvious right away that they've made an error.

I'd even settle for a way to show a little caret or something underneath so that they can spot the location of the error.

Comment: You can add a TextWatcher to see when the text changes.  You'd need to define what "wrong" is though.

Comment: But how would I set the formatting on just one part of the EditText's contents?

Comment: You use a Spannable.  Spannables are CharSequences with basic formatting attached. For an underline, it would be an UnderlineSpan https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/UnderlineSpan

Answer (score 1):

This is what I settled on.

`checkText()` gets called from `doAfterTextChanged` and when focus is lost, to clear the existing formatting.

The ViewModel then parses the text; it receives `addValidityStyleToRange` as a parameter and uses it to apply formatting as it goes.

```
    private fun checkText() {
        clearValidityStyles()
        viewModel.parseText(binding.edittext.text.toString(), ::addValidityStyleToRange)
    }

    /**
     * Clears the styles used for valid and invalid regions of edittext.
     */
    private fun clearValidityStyles() {
        val text = binding.edittext.text
        text.getSpans(0, text.length, UnderlineSpan::class.java).forEach { text.removeSpan(it) }
        text.getSpans(0, text.length, StyleSpan::class.java).forEach { text.removeSpan(it) }
    }

    /**
     * Applies the valid or invalid style to a range of edittext.
     * Passed as a callback to the ViewModel that validates the input.
     */
    private fun addValidityStyleToRange(range : IntRange, isValid : Boolean) {
        val text = binding.edittext.text
        val style = if (isValid) StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC) else UnderlineSpan()
        text.setSpan(style, range.first, range.last, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).